# Filter expression at runtime in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

I have applied a filter expression for group level like this in SSRS 2008 R2:

```
=((Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value >= Parameters!CasesShipped.Value 
    And Fields!Stocked.Value In('','Yes','No'))
Or
    (Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value < Parameters!CasesShipped.Value 
    And Fields!Stocked.Value In('Yes','')))
```

Here `Cases_Shipped` is the name of the column in which the filter has to be applied
when we select a value of cases shipped value from a drop down list.

`Stocked` is another column.

Criteria is working ok at sql server but in this manner in SSRS it shows error.

```
The FilterExpression expression for the tablix ‘table1’ contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.
```

Help Please!!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the problem - you haven't closed your brackets. You are missing the final ) to close the first open bracket.

```
=(  (Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value >= Parameters!CasesShipped.Value 
    And Fields!Stocked.Value In('','Yes','No'))
Or
    (Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value < Parameters!CasesShipped.Value 
    And Fields!Stocked.Value In('Yes','')) )
```

Comment: I have closed that brackets ,but it is not shown in the post,please click the edit button n you will see the same. it shows the error by closing the brackets also.

Comment: Okay, I edited your post so that it shows your code better, but what you entered is still missing the final closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in return that is missing from the above expression.

Kindly add the result what you want from this expression.